Unable to execute command in Kubernetes Pod container via Golang code
I am trying to connect to kubernetes cluster using below code.
I am loading the kubeconfig and passing the namespace and fetching all the pods.
I want to execute commands inside each container pods which is nothing but say mongodb instances.
$kubectl get pods -n mongo
mongo-0
mongo-1
mongo-2 

I have used this code kubernetes exec using golang
In below code snippet:
pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods("default").List(context.Background(), v1.ListOptions{})
        if err != nil {
                fmt.Printf("error getting pods: %v\n", err)
                os.Exit(1)
        }
        for _, pod := range pods.Items {
                fmt.Printf("Pod name: %s\n", pod.Name)
                //ExecuteRemoteCommand(pod.Name,"ls -ltr")
        }

I have just commented out the ExecuteRemoteCommand which will take pod name and command string and finally execute the command on the pod.
I was also looking into this discussion for executing command on the pod but, i didn't get any fruitful result:
Please help, i am new to golang and kubernetes.

What are you actually trying to do?  I'd try to avoid running arbitrary commands inside containers: you need Kubernetes-specific setup to do it, you'll typically have multiple replicas of a Deployment but an "exec" call will only affect one of them, and if you think of a Pod as a wrapper around a container as a wrapper around a process, the model doesn't quite make sense (how would you "go inside" your running Go program and run another command there?).  Can you approach this problem another way, maybe via an API call?  What specific problem are you running into?

@DavidMaze yes, you ar right. I wanted to connect to databse pod and execute some query ( may be via API )

Use a normal database library (an adapter into the standard library database/sql, gorm, ...) for this.  Don't do anything Kubernetes-specific in your code.  If the program will run outside the cluster, kubectl port-forward a connection to it.

I have a go file which can run command in a nginx Pod, is that what you want?
go.mod
module my.com/test
                                                    
go 1.20 

require (                                                            
        k8s.io/api v0.28.4                            
        k8s.io/client-go v0.28.4                                           
        k8s.io/kubectl v0.28.4                              
) 

main.go
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"

    v1 "k8s.io/api/core/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/remotecommand"
    "k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/scheme"
)

func executeCommandInPod(kubeconfigPath, pod, namespace, command string) (string, string, error) {
    // Build kubeconfig from the provided path
    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", kubeconfigPath)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("failed to build kubeconfig: %v", err)
    }

    // Create a new clientset based on the provided kubeconfig
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("failed to create clientset: %v", err)
    }

    // Get the pod's name and namespace
    podName := pod
    podNamespace := namespace

    // Build the command to be executed in the pod
    cmd := []string{"sh", "-c", command}

    // Execute the command in the pod
    req := clientset.CoreV1().RESTClient().Post().
        Resource("pods").
        Name(podName).
        Namespace(podNamespace).
        SubResource("exec").
        VersionedParams(&v1.PodExecOptions{
            Command: cmd,
            Stdin:   false,
            Stdout:  true,
            Stderr:  true,
            TTY:     false,
        }, scheme.ParameterCodec)

    executor, err := remotecommand.NewSPDYExecutor(config, "POST", req.URL())
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("failed to create executor: %v", err)
    }

    var stdout, stderr bytes.Buffer
    err = executor.Stream(remotecommand.StreamOptions{
        Stdout: &stdout,
        Stderr: &stderr,
        Tty:    false,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return "", "", fmt.Errorf("failed to execute command in pod: %v", err)
    }

    return stdout.String(), stderr.String(), nil
}

func main() {
    stdout, stderr, err := executeCommandInPod("/tmp/config", "nginx-0", "default", "ls /")
    fmt.Println(stdout, stderr, err)
}

